# How to bypass error processing checkout in woocommerce?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building custom payment gateway which will process the payment through ajax. It is working properly but for 1 second it is showing error display and redirecting to next page.

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",                                          
        url:http://example.com
        data: response,
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {                                  
            window.location = response.redirect; // order view page                                
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: With the information you have provided it can be very hard for us to help you figure out the problem. like you write `http://example.com`, i assume it's because you don't want to show us the real url? also what triggers your `ajax` call?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `JSON.parse(response);`?

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",                                          
    url:http://example.com
    data: response,
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {    
        var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
        window.location = responseObj.redirect; // order view page                                
    }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I have to bypass the error on place order through ajax

Comment: please post your response and explain the exact issue